# How to secure http4s webapp with keycloak?

Tags: scala, jetty, jetty-9, http4s

I would like to secure my Http4s based webapp with Keycloak, which is described on https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_jetty9_adapter.

The http4s webapp runs on Jetty as you can see on the code snippet

```
object UserSvcServer {

  def stream[F[_]: ConcurrentEffect](implicit T: Timer[F], C: ContextShift[F]): Stream[F, Nothing] = {

    val helloWorldAlg = HelloWorld.impl[F]
    val httpApp = (
      UserSvcRoutes.helloWorldRoutes[F](helloWorldAlg)
      ).orNotFound

    val finalHttpApp = Logger.httpApp(true, true)(httpApp)

    for {

      exitCode <- JettyBuilder[F]
        .bindHttp(8080, "0.0.0.0")
        .mountHttpApp(finalHttpApp, "/")
        .serve
    } yield exitCode
  }.drain

}
```

and I do not have to download the jetty container from https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/.

Is there a way to secure the Http4s based webapp with Keycloak jetty adapter?